# Set order of columns in JTable

Tags: java, jtable

I have a JTable with some columns. I have a HashMap of the column identifier mapped to the position in the view, for example:

```
TableHeader1 | TableHeader2 | TableHeader3
    sth.           sth.          sth.
```

I know that:

```
TableHeader1 -> position 0
TableHeader2 -> position 1
TableHeader3 -> position 2
```

Now I want to reorder the columns. I know that there is a function called moveColumn(A, B) within the JTable class. This moves a column from A to B, and B is putted left or right. 
My problem is, I want to order the whole table in a specific way, how can I do this?
If I use moveColumn, I cannot know where B has been moved, in 5 out of 10 cases it might be the right side and in the other cases the wrong side.

Hope you understand my problem :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the columns order by removing all of them and adding them in the right order:

```
public static void setColumnOrder(int[] indices, TableColumnModel columnModel) {
    TableColumn column[] = new TableColumn[indices.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
        column[i] = columnModel.getColumn(indices[i]);
    }

    while (columnModel.getColumnCount() > 0) {
        columnModel.removeColumn(columnModel.getColumn(0));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
        columnModel.addColumn(column[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK how about this. Might be a bit left field.

Extend `TableColumn` and give your new class a `position` property. Have it implement `Comparable` and use the `position` to compare columns.

Next, extend `DefaultTableColumnModel` and store `TableColumn`s in an ordered list.

Your JTable should now display columns according to their `position`. Untested but it sounds interesting so I might give it a go later.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Guillaume answer I found a way to do that without the need to remove all columns and add them again.

```
  public static void setColumnOrder(int[] indices, JTable table, TableColumnModel columnModel) {

    for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
      columnModel.moveColumn(i, table.convertColumnIndexToView(indices[i]));
    }
  }
```

This works better for me because with (SwingX) JXTable, the order of the invisible columns is not modified.

Comment: This will not work! For example reverse the order of the columns like that: 4 3 2 1 0. It will end up like 4 1 3 2 0. Thats because some columns get moved twice.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by using the built in moveColumn function as a bubble sort shortcut. The hashmap holds your weights in that case. Keep in mind that *getColumnModel().getColumn(j).getModelIndex()* can be seen as the initial column index / ID that will not change. See it as a column title.

```
HashMap<int, int> mapOrder = new HashMap<int, int>();

for (int i = 0; i < jt_table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < jt_table.getColumnCount() - 1; j++) {
        int col1 = mapOrder.get(jt_table.getColumnModel().getColumn(j).getModelIndex());
        int col2 = mapOrder.get(jt_table.getColumnModel().getColumn(j + 1).getModelIndex());
        if (col1 > col2) {
            jt_table.moveColumn(jt_table.getColumnModel().getColumn(j).getModelIndex(), jt_table.getColumnModel().getColumn(j + 1).getModelIndex());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reorder by column name then you can check out the [Table Column Reordering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/table-column-reordering/) suggestion.